# Replace pandas dataframe values within a particular column based on values within a different column

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

Given the following dataframe:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 2, 3, 2], "b_1": [0, 0, 0, 0], "b_2": [0, 0, 0, 0], "b_3": [0, 0, 0, 0]}
)
```

Which looks as:

```
   a  b_1  b_2  b_3
0  1    0    0    0
1  2    0    0    0
2  3    0    0    0
3  2    0    0    0
```

How can it be coverted to:

```py
y = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 2],
        "b_1": [-1, 0, 0, 0],
        "b_2": [0, -1, 0, -1],
        "b_3": [0, 0, -1, 0],
    }
)
```

which looks as:

```
   a  b_1  b_2  b_3
0  1   -1    0    0
1  2    0   -1    0
2  3    0    0   -1
3  2    0   -1    0
```

## edit 2

Here's a solution:

```py
x1 = x.melt(id_vars="a", ignore_index=False)
x1["value_2"] = x1["variable"].str.split("_").str[1].astype(int)
x1.loc[x1["a"].eq(x1["value_2"]), "value"] = -1
x1 = x1.drop("value_2", axis=1)
x1.set_index(["a", "variable"], append=True)["value"].unstack().reset_index(level=1)
x1 = x1.set_index(["a", "variable"], append=True)["value"].unstack().reset_index(level=1)
```

I feel as though it's quite messy though.

Comment: What's the rule behind where You want to put -1 in y ?

Comment: @PiotrNowakowski sorry - the rule here is that the value in `a` is the same as the value of the suffix in the `b_*` columns

Comment: Okey but `-1` is still confusing. I don't know what rules You want to apply in transformation from `x` to `y`. Suffix just shed some light on `a` column

Comment: the -1 is a specified value - it could be `-100` really - but it's based on there being a match between the value in `a` and the value of the suffix.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

```
print(pd.get_dummies(x['a']).add_prefix('b_'))
   b_1  b_2  b_3
0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0
2    0    0    1
3    0    1    0
```

Then you have different options to substract it from `x`. For example, you can use this way with `reindex`.

```
y = x - pd.get_dummies(x['a']).add_prefix('b_').reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=0)
print(y)
   a  b_1  b_2  b_3
0  1   -1    0    0
1  2    0   -1    0
2  3    0    0   -1
3  2    0   -1    0
```

Note that if you don't have the column `b_*` already in `x` and want to generate them automatically from the column a, then something like this would work too.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 2]})
y = x.sub(pd.get_dummies(x['a']).add_prefix('b_'), fill_value=0)
print(y)
```

Comment: thanks I'll review this! I added an approach i took , which felt a bit messy

Comment: @baxx indeed it is a bit more code than the single line above :)

Comment: yeah - though i realise that your approach won't work when there are other values in the dataframe... which is annoying (on my part) as i didn't think of this when writing the example :S thanks tho, i'll edit later if necessary, or just ask a different q with different detail